# Fourier transform of translated Dirac Delta.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

Solve:
$$ y'' + 6y' +5y = \delta(t-3)$$ using Fourier's Transform.

---

$$\mathcal{F}\{y'' + 6y' +5y\} = \mathcal{F}\{\delta(t-3)\}$$

$$ \mathcal{F}\{y\}\left[(iw)^2 + 6iw + 5\right]= \mathcal{F}\{\delta(t-3)\}$$

$$\mathcal{F}\{y\} = \frac{\mathcal{F}\{\delta(t-3)\}}{(iw + 5)(iw + 1)}$$

---

I know that ${F}\{\delta(t)\}=1$, what happens with ${F}\{\delta(t-a)\}$?

Comment: Write down the definition of the Fourier transform of $f(t-a)$ (for arbitrary $f$) and perform a substitution $t' = t-a$ to get $\mathcal{F}\{f(t-a)\}$ in terms of $\mathcal{F}\{f(t)\}$.

Comment: Using the property $$\langle \delta_a,f\rangle =f(a)$$, we have $$\mathscr{F}\{\delta_3\}=e^{-i3\omega}$$

Comment: Just as reference, a solution that is zero on negative $t$ (or $t<3$) will have the form $y(x)=u(t)H(t-3)$ where $H$ is the Heaviside ramp function and $u$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation with $u(3)=0$, $u'(3)=1$. Thus
$$
u(t)=\frac{1}{4}(e^{-(t-3)}-e^{-5(t-3)}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{d^2y(t)}{dt^2} + 6\frac{dy(t)}{dt} +5y(t) = \delta(t-3)$$
Of course, one can compute the $\mathcal{F}\{\delta(t-3)\}$ from the definition of the Fourier transform.

But, knowing $\mathcal{F}\{\delta(t)\}$ the solution is straightforward with the change of variable :
$$T=t-3\qquad\to\qquad \frac{d^2y(T)}{dT^2} + 6\frac{dy(T)}{dT} +5y(T) = \delta(T)$$